# codeigniter upload 3gp or mp4 files doesnt work

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, mp4, 3gp

hi I am trying to upload 3gp and mp4 files on code igniter and it doesnt work

the mpg files are uploaded fine using the same code could anyone help me with that I will really appreciate that

Here is the code i am using

```
            $config = array(

               'allowed_types' => 'mp4|mp4|3gp|mpg';
               'file_name'     => 'video',
               'max_size'      => 1000,
               'upload_path'   => realpath(APPPATH.'../user_uploads/'),
                            );

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);

            $this->upload->do_upload();


            $user_upload = $this->upload->data();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add your mime type in the config/mimes.php file. Like for 3gp:

```
'3gp'=>'video/3gpp'
```

List of available mime types : http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Comment: can u tell me the mime type for mp4

Comment: 'mp4'=>'video/mp4' use this for mp4 :)

Comment: check your file mime type and add them in mimes.php file. var_dump($_FILES['my_upload']['type']);  use this function

Comment: Old question, but here is a list of mime types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Answer (score 3):

**application/config/mimes.php**

```
'3gp' => array(
    'video/mp4', 
    'video/3gp', 
    'video/3gpp', 
    'video/x-3gp', 
    'flv-application/octet-stream', 
    'application/octet-stream', 
    'inode/x-empty'
),
'mp4' => array(
    'video/mp4', 
    'video/3gpp',
    'application/octet-stream'
),
```

Answer (score 1):

add mime type for **.3gp** in `$mimes` array in   below files

**application/config/mimes.php**

```
'3gp'   =>  array('video/3gpp', 'video/x-3gp', 'flv-application/octet-stream', 'application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the allowed types of files which can be uploaded

```
 $config = array(
               'file_name'     => 'video',
               'max_size'      => 1000,
               'allowed_types'] = 'mp4|mp4|3gp'
               'upload_path'   => realpath(APPPATH.'../user_uploads/'),
                );
```

and if the mime type you put in upload cofig doesn't exist in `/config/mimes.php` . add it there also

Comment: have you defined the mime types in ./config/mimes.php ?

Comment: what should be the mime type for 3gp and mp4